# Menu like android built in places app

Tags: android-layout, android

I want to make a menu like android built in `Places` application. can any one tell me how this menu is built ?

[image]

Comment: Its dashboard design pattern, you have to use a GridView.

Comment: You can use the gridview for such type of menu's implementation and set the total number of columns by 2.

Answer (score 0):

As already commented, this is a Dashboard layout. You can draw this using [GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) in android. A very nice tutorial for your exact need is given at this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/12/android-dashboard-design-tutorial/).

Answer (score 0):

You can create the menu like a dashboard layout similar to the facebook dashboard. Use [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/12/android-dashboard-design-tutorial/) as layout and fill it with Buttons or other elements you like.

I hope it will help you.

Thanks.